# No such directory when using Pool to read file

Tags: python

I'm new to python multiprocessing. I'm trying to read excel file with enormous file size. When reading big files it takes a long time and I just found out about Multiprocessing `It is the technology that allows your program to run in parallel by using multiple CPU cores at the same time. It is used to significantly speed up your program` I'm trying to use it but when I read it via Pool, it returns error no such file or directory but without pool (just call the function with the parameter) it doesn't raise error.

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
import multiprocessing as mp

def read_csv(filename):
    return pd.read_csv(filename)


def main():
    myfile = "C:\\excel_processor\\1_wht_escrow_verified_id -1.csv"

    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    mydf = pool.map(read_csv, myfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a large csv file with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas)

Comment: No, because the data can also be other format than csv (e.g xlsx, xlsb, etc)